# sql server does not take most restrictive condition for execution plan

Tags: sql, sql-server

We have a query with multiple joins where sql server 2016 does not take the optimal path and we cannot convince it without hints (which we prefer not to use)
Simplified the problem is as follows :

Table A (12 million rows)
Table B (type table, 5 rows)
Table C (12 million rows)

query (simplified to clarify)

```
SELECT 
     [A].[ID]                   
    ,[A].[DATE_CREATED]         
    ,[A].[DATE_LAST_MODIFIED]   
    ,[A].[CODE]
    ,[B].[CODE]                 
    ,[B].[DESCRIPTION]          
    ,[C].[EVENT_ID]             
    ,[C].[SOURCE_REFERENCE]     
    ,[C].[EVTY_ID]              
    ,[C].[BUSINESS_KEY]         
    ,[C].[DATA]                 
    ,[C].[EVENT_DATE]           
FROM A
    JOIN B  ON [B].[ID] = [A].[PSTY_ID] AND [B].[ACTIVE] = 1
    JOIN C  ON [C].[ID] = [B].[EVEN_ID] AND [C].[ACTIVE] = 1
    WHERE [B].[CODE] = 'nopr' OR [B].[CODE] = 'inpr'
```

the selected codes from B correspond to values 1 and 2

Table A contain max 10 PSTY_ID values 1 or 2 the rest is 3,4 or 5

There is a foreign key from A.PSTY_ID to B.ID

There is a filtered index on table A PSTY_ID 1,2 and all selected columns as included columns

The optimizer does not seem to recognize that we try to select values 1 and 2, and does not use the index or start with table B (trying to force with subqueries or changing table order do not help, only the hint OPTION  (FORCE ORDER) can convince the optimizer, but this we do not want)

Only when we hard code the B.ID or A.PSTY_ID values 1 and 2 in the where clause the optimizer takes the correct path, starting with table B.

If we do not do this, it starts to join table A with table C, and only then with table B, leading to vastly more processing time (approx 50X)

We also tried to declare the values and using them as variables, but still no luck.

Would anyone know if this is a known issue, or if this can be worked around ?

Comment: >>>The optimizer does not seem to recognize that we try to select values 1 and 2<<< Not only optimizer does it. It's not written anywhere in your query that you  want  PSTY_ID 1,2, so, for example, I too cannot deduce it

Comment: Try wrapping the query for Table B in a CTE. (SELECT CODE, DESCRIPTION FROM B WHERE......) Take the WHERE clause of the query into the CTE then replace joining B with joining the CTE. This is assuming there WHERE part equates to values 1 and 2 only from B?

Comment: @Dave Brown At execution time CTE will be substituted with its query, so it changes NOTHING

Comment: Thanks for having a look. I tried the option with a subselect looking up only the B.CODE 'nopr' and 'inpr'  (these are B.ID 1 and 2, matching A.PSTY_ID 1 and 2) Still the optimizer chooses to first join table A and C.

Answer (score 0):

Your `filtered index` will not be used in this case unless you include values `1` and `2` in the `where` clause, you cannot change this even if you try to join with the table that ONLY has `1`,`2` in its rows.

`Filtered index` will **never be used based on some "assumptions"** of what values some table (physical or derived like `CTE` or `subquery`), and in fact your subquery did not help.
So if you want to use it, you should add the `where` condition equivalent to those of filtered index to your query.

Since you don't want to add this condition, but still want to change join order of your tables starting with `B` table you can use `temporary table`/`table variable` like this:

```
select [ID] 
      ,[CODE]                 
      ,[DESCRIPTION] 
      ,[EVEN_ID]
into #tmp              
from B
where ([CODE] = 'nopr' OR [CODE] = 'inpr') and [ACTIVE] = 1
```

And now use this `#tmp` instead of `B` in your query.